# Node.js WebSocket server is only accepting one client from my local machine

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, server, ws

I have a really simple Node.js server that uses 'ws' for WebSockets, but it's only accepting one client in what I believe is a multi-client server.

Here's literally the program I'm using to test it right now. Short and simple, but isn't working.

```js
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

let server = new https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/private.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/certificate.crt"),
    ca: fs.readFileSync("./ssl/ca_bundle.crt")
}).listen(443);

let wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    noServer: true
});

server.on("upgrade", (request, socket, head) => {
    wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
        ws.onopen = (event) => {
            console.log("A client has connected");
        };
        ws.onclose = (event) => {
            console.log("A client has disconnected");
        }
    });
});
```

Both clients are running the same code in Google Chrome (Also tested with firefox)
Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("wss://example.com/ws/");
            ws.onopen = function(e){
                console.log("Open: ", e);
            }
            ws.onmessage = function(e){
                console.log("Message: ", e);
            }
            ws.onerror = function(e){
                console.log("Error: ", e);
            }
            ws.onclose = function(e){
                console.log("Close: ", e);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

One client will log the open connection, every other client will log a timeout, error, and close event. Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly do you observe that makes you say it's only accepting one client?  How are you making the 2nd connection?  What happens in both client and server when you attempt to make the second connection?

Comment: Edited original question. Thanks for your time

Comment: When I change the server to http (since I don't have your https certificates), I cannot reproduce your problem.  I can happily connect with multiple tabs all from Chrome.

Comment: I still haven't gotten this to work. Just tried reinstalling nodejs, didn't work. Tried uploading it to an alternate machine, also didn't work. Nothing seems to want to work. I think it might have something to do with my router, but I'm not 100% sure. I have AT&T, so I have a feeling that's what's wrong as I've had problems with their router in the past.

Comment: You mentioned your router.  Why do you think that has anything to do with it?  Are you trying to connect from outside your network to a server inside the home network?  If so, that would require a port forwarding hole in the firewall.

Comment: I have port forwarding already set up. I have a friend who helped me test my server and everything works according to plan. When I try to connect from more than one computer on the local network, however, it doesn't work, but my friend could have as many tabs and computers connected on his wifi connecting to the server on my wifi.

Comment: Thank you for your time though man, It just looks to me like the router doesn't take the time to prepare the request properly if it isn't leaving the LAN.